# How to add guidelines to MPAndroidChart-PieChart?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

This is my project:the data isn't true, how can I add guideline to my project?
I try to draw line with canvas but the pie slice changed then the line how to follow ?

```java
public class PieChartActivity extends Activity {

private PieChart mPieChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pie_chart);

    mPieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
    PieData mPieData = getPieData(5,100);
    showChart(mPieChart, mPieData);
}

private void showChart (PieChart pieChart,PieData pieData){
    pieChart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);

    pieChart.setHoleRadius(60f);
    pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(64f);

    pieChart.setDescription("今日资金统计表"); 
    pieChart.setDescriptionTextSize(18f);
    pieChart.setDrawCenterText(true); 
    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);

    pieChart.setRotationAngle(90);  
    pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);  

    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true); 
    pieChart.setCenterText("今日资金"); 

    pieChart.setData(pieData); 
    Legend mLegend = pieChart.getLegend(); 
    mLegend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART); 

    mLegend.setXEntrySpace(7f); 
    mLegend.setYEntrySpace(5f);
    pieChart.animateXY(1500, 1500); 
}

private PieData getPieData (int count,float range){
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    xVals.add("小单买入");
    xVals.add("小单卖出");
    xVals.add("大单买入");
    xVals.add("大单卖出");
    xVals.add("其他");

    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>(); 
    float data1 = 14;
    float data2 = 25;
    float data3 = 19;
    float data4 = 38;
    float data5 = 4;
    yVals.add(new Entry(data1, 0));
    yVals.add(new Entry(data2, 1));
    yVals.add(new Entry(data3, 2));
    yVals.add(new Entry(data4, 3));
    yVals.add(new Entry(data5, 4));

    PieDataSet mPieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals, "比例图");
    mPieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);  

    ArrayList<Integer>  colors =  new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    colors.add(Color.rgb(255, 73, 75));
    colors.add(Color.rgb(79, 145, 255));
    colors.add(Color.rgb(255, 152, 152));
    colors.add(Color.rgb(252, 184, 64));
    colors.add(Color.rgb(140, 201, 158));
    mPieDataSet.setColors(colors);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = 5*(metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    mPieDataSet.setSelectionShift(px); 

    PieData pieData = new PieData(xVals,mPieDataSet);
    pieData.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    return pieData;
}
}
```

Just like the following picture,

[image: please click here to look at my picture]

Comment: this is not possible MPChart